# Django session strange behavior: Invalid literal for Decimal: '2011-01-04 09:36:59' error

Tags: django, django-sessions

i'm getting this error while trying to retrieve a session content from the django_session table on my web app. I'm using request.session.get('mykey_name')
The query django performs to get this is:

`s = Session.objects.get(session_key = self.session_key,expire_date__gt=datetime.datetime.now()`

The kwargs are: {'expire_date__gt': datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 21, 14, 27, 6, 138883), 'session_key': '721c947a60432c3ac3bbdd485931c945'}

Here is the full traceback:

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  80.                     response = middleware_method(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyfacegraph-0.0.4-py2.7.egg/facegraph/django/middleware.py" in process_request
  46.         request.graph = self.graph_for_request(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyfacegraph-0.0.4-py2.7.egg/facegraph/django/middleware.py" in graph_for_request
  51.         access_token = self.access_token(request)
File "/home/roohitne/djangoCode/roohit/fb/middleware.py" in access_token
  7.         return request.session.get('access_token')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py" in get
  63.         return self._session.get(key, default)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py" in _get_session
  172.                 self._session_cache = self.load()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py" in load
  20.                 expire_date__gt=datetime.datetime.now()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in get
  132.         return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  336.         num = len(clone)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __len__
  81.                 self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in iterator
  269.         for row in compiler.results_iter():
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in results_iter
  672.         for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  727.         cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py" in execute
  15.             return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in execute
  86.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.2-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
  166.             self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.2-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py" in defaulterrorhandler
  35.     raise errorclass, errorvalue

Exception Type: InvalidOperation at /oauth/callback/
Exception Value: Invalid literal for Decimal: '2011-01-04 14:04:39'
```

I'm usig django 1.2.3 and python 2.7 and the database version is 5.1.33-community under CentOS.
Any guesses why is this happening?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have no access to Django from here, but apparently a Decimal instead of a datetime (or a string) is expected.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a very obscure problem. All I can find on it is this thread:
http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/2e04a75e5da3c278

Did you upgrade or migrate the DB recently? Is the problem persistent in a newly `syncdb` database? Might want to rule that one out.

Since the error returns `2011-01-04 14:04:39` when you haven't supplied that information, something is successfully writing to the DB and reading from it but something else is converting it to a decimal... Unfortunately I don't know how / when django or mysqldb tries to convert datetime to a decimal

If nobody answers I'd reach out to the guy in the link above because it's literally the single mention on the internets.

Comment: Yes, i also found that only reference but without any solution.

Comment: (OOPS i presed enter, continuation from last msg). I developed the django project on another server and migrated it to this one. On the developement server worked fine. I did a syncdb and removed the django_sessions table several times with no luck. The app creates the session and all works fine on the first page it loads, bit on the next pages i get that error reading the database... I'll try contact that guy to see if he solved it, thanks for your answer.

Comment: I give up! dug through mysqldb..  Looks like Ignacio is on the move for you @ the google groups :) I wish you luck.

Comment: Yes, Ignacio it's me :) Thanks, I'll update the post if i find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is related to php and python running in the same apache instance,

When I commented the line

```
LoadModule php5_module                    /usr/lib/apache2/mod_php5.so
```

in httpd.conf, it started working normally.